# Combinatorics on a string of letters

Tags: combinatorics

Define a *word* to be any distinct rearrangement of $AAAABBBCCDE$. There are four $A$'s, three $B$'s, two $C$'s, one $D$, one $E$.

(a) How many words have all the $B$'s together?

(b) How many words don't contain all four $A$'s together (some might be together, but not all)?

(c) How many words start with $D$ but don't end with $E$?

(d) How many words have $D$ before $E$?

---

I think for (a), there are $9$ places for the $BBB$ to go. Then there are eight other letters, which can be rearranged among themselves in $\frac{8!} {(4!2!)}$ ways. So I got $\frac {9 \cdot 8!} {(4 ! 2!)}$ which is $7560$.

(b) Count the opposite and subtract from the total. I think (not sure) that there are $138600$ total arrangements. Then there are $8$ places for the $AAAA$ to go, and I can rearrange the other letters among themselves in $\frac  {7!} {(3!  2!)}$ ways. So I got $ 138600 - \frac {8 \cdot 7!} {(3! 2!)}$ which is $135240$.

(c) The D has to be first. There are $9$ choices for where E goes, and I can interchange the other letters for every choice of E's position. So I got $ \frac {9 \cdot 9!} {(4! 3! 2!)} = 11340$.

(d) I guess $\frac {138600} {2}$ (total divided by two). This is just my intuition though. I don't know for sure.

---

Are my answers correct?

Comment: They all look right to me.  In part d) notice that the permutations where D precedes E are in one-to-one correspondence with those where E precedes D.  (Just swap the two letters.)

Comment: @astronomer6353 Why did you delete your question on round table combinatorics? Ross Millikan provided an answer to help you out, you asked for additional explanation (and got it), and then deleted your question. This is not recommended!